# How to parse this?

Tags: android, json, parsing, arrays

Friends please help me to parse this response using Json object and json array concept
I get all field as Strings for displaying

```
{"status": "OK", 
 "data": {
       "passenger": [
               {"status": "S2 , 26", 
               "seat_number": "RAC 53,GNWL"}, 
               {"status": "S2 , 27", "seat_number": "RAC 54,GNWL"}], 
       "from": {"code": "MAQ", 
               "name": "MANGALORE", 
               "time": "14:40"}, 
       "chart_prepared": true, 
       "alight": 
               {"code": "LTT", 
               "name": "LOKMANYA TILAK (T)", 
               "time": "06:35"}, 
       "pnr_number": "4243907794", 
       "train_number": "12620", 
       "to":   {"code": "LTT", 
               "name": "LOKMANYA TILAK (T)", 
               "time": "06:35"}, 
       "board": {"timestamp": 1344849000, 
               "code": "MAQ", 
               "name": "MANGALORE", 
               "time": "14:40"}, 
       "train_name": "MATSYAGANDA EXP", 
       "travel_date": {"date": "13-8-2012", 
               "timestamp": 1344796200}, 
       "class": "SL"
       }
 }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO -- before asking questions, you need to make sure that you do a couple of things. First, make sure that before asking, you've already made a clear attempt at solving your own problem. Questions on SO should generally be of the form "I tried X, and Y happened. What might I be doing wrong and what can I do to fix it?" You also need to be more specific about what your problem is. In this case, JSon can be parsed as just about anything. I could parse it as hebrew if you paid me enough. Make sure your questions clearly express what kind of answer you're looking to get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here in above image of structure of your JSON 
[image]

you should better use http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ and paste your json here to view and understand its structure and then can use GSON or any other library to parse it and get what you want out of it

Comment: Hi i need a method to parse this value.

Comment: check the following links.. i hope they will help. http://androidsmith.com/2011/07/using-gson-to-parse-json-on-android/   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8385470/getting-specific-object-of-xml-which-can-be-parsed-using-xstream

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://www.json.org/java/, instantiate a new JSONObject with your string as the first argument and continue from there.